# How to set Ubuntu with Cinnamon to hibernate when lid is closed with external monitor?

Tags: power-management, hibernate, cinnamon

If I have external monitor attached, closing lid won't hibernate my computer. In normal Ubuntu I could edit this in power settings but how could I set my Ubuntu with Cinnamon to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If not already installed, install `dconf-editor` with

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Then open it and navigate to
*org.cinnamon.settings-daemon.plugins.power*
and tick
*lid-close-suspend-with-external-monitor*.

Close dconf-editor and it should be working.